# Is this git's correct behavior for "git add" with subfolders?

Tags: git, msysgit

When using "git add" with a file pattern it only adds recursively the untracked files, and ignores the changed ones unless they are in the current folder.

Example:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#    (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:    level1/test1.txt
#       modified:    level1/level2/test1.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to incldude in what will be committed)
# 
#       level1/test2.txt
#       level1/level2/test2.txt
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git add level1\*.txt
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   level1/level2/test2.txt
#       new file:   level1/test2.txt
#
# Changed but not updated:
#       modified:   level1/level2/test1.txt
#       modified:   level1/test1.txt
#
```

After I execute `git add level1\*.txt`, the untracked (test2.txt) files are added, but not the modified (test1.txt) files. I've tried with the -u option, escaping and not escaping the asterisk, etc. but nothing seems to simply be able to add ALL files matching a pattern whether they are tracked or not.

Of course in this example I could just add all the files with -A, but keep in mind this is just for the purpose of this question, in reality there will be more files and I would not want to add them all, and the hierarchy is a few folders deeper. The only way for me to add the tracked files is referring to the directing or writing the whole pattern except for the file name like this: `git add level1**.txt` OR `git add level1/level2/*.txt`.

In the git add documentation: [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) it says that the file pattern is supposed to work recursively and doesn't say anything about tracked or untracked files and it even gives and example.

I'm using msysgit but I've tested this on Windows and Linux just in case.

I just want to know. Am I interpreting the documentation correctly (because I think based on the docs it should work) or is this how it is supposed to work? It just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your setup or problem, I can't reproduce this at all. I set myself up to get output from git status exactly like yours, then ran `git add level1/*.txt`, and as expected, level1/test1.txt and level1/test2.txt were added (one modified, one new file), but not the two files in level2. (Were you expecting it to match the files in level2? The `*` doesn't work across directories.)

Comment: Okay, I believe I found what you mean. If I run `git add "level1/*.txt"` (the quotes cause the `*` to be handled by git, not by the shell), I get your behavior: the test2 files (new) are added, but not the test1 (modified). Interesting. (I misread this the first time - thought that the `\` was meant to be a windows directory separator. I don't use msysgit.)

Comment: (Er, in that previous comment, `\` should've been `\\`.) I've edited the question to be a little clearer with the example, after reproducing this myself. If I've messed up anything (in particular to do with directory separators vs backslash escaping) please fix it!

Comment: Wow, I've never failed quite so hard at comment markup.

Comment: I'd bring this up on the [git mailing list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git).  It does not seem to be meant this way.

Comment: @Sven: Yeah, I was hoping someone might chime in with an explanation, but I certainly can't come up with any good reason for this behavior.

Comment: Yeah, before bringing it up with the git mailing list or reporting anything I just wanted to get some input from other people and make sure it wasn't just me doing something wrong which I consider to be very likely since I'm just starting out with git. When you have a problem like this and you Google and don't seem to find anybody with the same issue, you start to think you are doing something wrong (which is what I still kinda think).

Comment: I believe that git will interpret the path in a linux style when parsing arguments which include paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, there might as well be an answer on this question.

No, that doesn't seem to be the right behavior at all. `git add <filepattern>` should be equivalent to `git add file1 file2...`, where those are the files matched by the pattern - and that's not what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use

```
git add level1\*.txt
```

Notes the back-slash <kbd>\</kbd>. This is equal to

```
git add 'level1*.txt'
```

To get the expected behavior, use slash <kbd>/</kbd>.

If you just want to add all files, use `git add -A .`

Comment: As a fairly experienced git user I'd say this is still unexpected behavior.

Comment: With "git add level1/*.txt" you would get added all the files ending in ".txt" within the level1 folder, but not the ones in its subfolders like level2. I am aware that you can just add all the files with "git add -A", but that is not the point here, we want the <filepattern> to work as expected (to match all files with a pattern...).